# MongoDB regex filter string array items

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Here is document structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6284f3eceae4fd4c3cfebb39"),
    "Codes" : [ 
        "Code 1",
        "Code 2",
        "Code 3"
    ]
}
```

Also i have mongo query which works as expected

```
{ "Codes" : { "$elemMatch" : { "$regex" : /code/, $options: 'si' } } }
```

But when i tried to write C# code with mongodb driver

```
var filter = Builders<MyClass>.Filter
    .ElemMatch(x => x.Codes,
        Builders<string>.Filter.Regex(c => c, new BsonRegularExpression($"/^{codeFilter}/is")));
```

and execute this filter definition i've got an exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the
> serialization information for c => c.'

Where is my mistake? How can i create filter definition to check string array items with `$regex` operator?

Answer (score 1):

You created wrong generic type for regex builder:

```
Builders<MyClass>.Filter.ElemMatch(
    x => x.Codes, 
    Builders<Codes>.Filter.Regex(
         c => c.Code, 
         new BsonRegularExpression($"/code/", "si")));
```

where the entities structure are:

```
    private class MyClass
    {
        public Codes[] Codes { get; set; }
    }

    private class Codes
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
```